# RxJS first() for Observable.of() - no elements in sequence

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

For my tests I am trying to mock an event stream with `Observable.of()` but when I try

```
const actions$ = Observable.of({});
...
// in the function that is tested
actions$
  .filter(action => action.type === 'LOAD_REQUEST') 
  .first()
  .subscribe(() => { ... do something });
```

I get the following error

> EmptyError: no elements in sequence in xxx.js

This only occurs when I use `.first()`.

How can I mock the event stream so the tests don't fail?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`.first()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-first) will emit exactly one item or throw an error (if no `defaultValue` parameter was provided), so calling it on an empty observable will cause an error. This is the expected behavior based on the documentation.

If you would like to get at most one item from the observable, use [`.take(1)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-take).

Comment: And if you would want to add `defaultValue`, where would you add? After o before `first`?

Comment: It would be something like `observable.pipe(first(undefined, undefined, "your default"))`. I didn't try it though

Answer (score 15):

The documentation for [`first()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-first) says:

> Delivers an EmptyError to the Observer's error callback if the Observable completes before any next notification was sent.

So the error happens because your test data don't pass the `filter()` operator and emit complete immediately.

Comment: Thanks for this prefect answer, it was really hard to decide who to give the "accept answer" to. While you explained me why I saw the error and what I did wrong Tamas gave me the solution for fixing it.