# EmptyError: no elements in sequence

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm upgrading my Angular2 app from 2.0.0 to 2.3.0, and I'm running into the following error.  Any ideas as to why?  I saw this other post ([Angular 2.0.1 Router EmptyError: no elements in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734085/angular-2-0-1-router-emptyerror-no-elements-in-sequence)), but after trying this, the issue still remains.  What causes this error?

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): EmptyError: no elements in sequence
Error: no elements in sequence
    at EmptyError.ZoneAwareError (zone.js:672)
    at new EmptyError (EmptyError.ts:13)
    at FirstSubscriber._complete (first.ts:161)
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.ts:122)
    at Subject._subscribe (Subject.ts:109)
    at Subject.Observable.subscribe (Observable.ts:98)
    at Observable._subscribe (Observable.ts:158)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.ts:98)
    at Observable._subscribe (Observable.ts:158)
    at FirstOperator.call (first.ts:82)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.ts:96)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.ts:32)
    at MergeAllSubscriber._next (mergeAll.ts:82)
    at MergeAllSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:80)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:475) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:460) [angular]
    at /libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:509:17 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.min.js:32) [angular]
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:261) [angular]
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:151) [<root> => angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:405) [<root>]
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:336) [<root>]ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.min.js:31next @ core.umd.min.js:32generatorOrNext.object.schedulerFn @ core.umd.min.js:32SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:238SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:190Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:135Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:95Subject.next @ Subject.ts:61EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.min.js:32NgZone.triggerError @ core.umd.min.js:32onHandleError @ core.umd.min.js:32ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:233Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:129_loop_1 @ zone.js:416drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:425ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:336
```

I've also noticed that a NavigationError object is thrown when I try to change to a route that uses Guards.  But only the error above is what is shown in the console.

`NavigationError {id: 2, url: "/home", error: EmptyError}`

I'm kind of at a loss and would appreciate any help.

Comment: So please show your routes..

Comment: I believe this is something to do with guards, I'm trying to figure it out as well.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

In my case I've got those errors when I used `first()` in an `Observable` that had a `takeUntil()` emitted before `first()`.

*Example:*

```js
let test$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
let testAux$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
let test2$ = test$.asObservable().takeUntil(testAux$.asObservable());
test2$.first().subscribe(() => console.log('first!'));
testAux$.next(null);
```

It was hard to discover the problem because I returned an `observable` with `takeUntil()` in a service that was used by a different class (in a different file) that called `first()`, and the error was received during page navigation (because `takeUntil()` received an `observable` that emitted when the previous page was destroyed), and it appeared as the problem was in the navigation itself.

The weirdest thing is that the error happens when the `next()` is called, and not in the 2nd argument of `subscribe()`, causing the navigation process itself to fail. I don't know if this feature was chosen by the rxjs team to behave this way, because it makes much more difficult to isolate the problem, and, the main problem, **the producer receives an error because of something done by a consumer**, which seems as a bad design to me.

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40849225/4850646):

> [.first()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-first) will emit exactly one item or throw an error[...] If you would like to get at most one item from the observable, use [.take(1)](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-take).

**Update (2020-08-31)**

It seems that the error can actually be handled by including a 2nd argument to receive errors in the subscription, like in the following case:

```js
const test$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
const testAux$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
const test2$ = test$.asObservable().takeUntil(testAux$.asObservable());
test2$.first().subscribe(() => console.log('first!'), () => console.log('first error'));
testAux$.subscribe(() => console.log('another'), () => console.log('another error'));
console.log('1');
testAux$.next(null);
console.log('2');
```

That logs:

```
1
first error
another
2
```

(in this case you wouldn't see the `No elements in sequence` error)

But if you want to receive at most 1 item (but it would still be fine to receive none), then `take(1)` would still be the better approach, and it is what I would recommend by default, instead of `first()`.

Comment: Changing a first() to a take(1) as recommended here fixed the similar error message "Error: no elements in sequence" for me.

Comment: In my case, a component was calling `.first()` on an empty Observable (the Observable was returned by a mock implementation of a service, so it only failed in unit tests).

Comment: @mamacdon same here. Good catch!

Comment: This thing happens easily when you have something in your `ngAfterViewInit` that does a `takeUntil(this.destroy$), first()`. And in your destroy, you trigger your `destroy$` flag. It would happen if you load a component, but somehow, you delete it quickly from a parent component in a `ngAfterViewInit`. Review all your `takeUntil(this.destroy$)` followed by `first()` and replace it with `take(1)`.

Answer (score 81):

This error happens when using RxJS 5.5.3 with angular (version 4/5), so just skip RxJS 5.5.3, and use RxJS 5.5.4 by adding `"rxjs": "^5.5.4"` to your project package.json.

---

**Before RxJS 5.5.4 came out answer: (old, don't do this)**

- Lock version 5.5.2 RxJS on package.json [source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3151)
- add pathMatch: 'full' on empty paths [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20752)

It looks like this is an [RxJS issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3151#issuecomment-348730503) which should be patched pretty soon. [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20752#issuecomment-348730926)

Comment: Can confirm, just upgraded to RxJS 5.5.3 and we have the same problem.

Comment: same here. broken.. Thanks golfadas. let me fix ours

Comment: Also confirmed. Something is wrong with 5.5.3 and Angular 5.0.0 (tested version)

Comment: Second option **Works** , Add `pathMatch: 'full'`  to all of your routes, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47612634/2218697) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhm22.png).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, as of the 5 december it's the current issue for that log

Comment: Have this problem with rxjs 6.5.2 and Angular 8. Already had pathMatch: 'full' for my empty route.

Answer (score 21):

You need change to:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean>{
   return new Observable<boolean>(resolve => {
      resolve.next(true);
      resolve.complete();
  });
}
```

================

I am unsure why but for me this error was caused by CanActivate router guards using observables. Moving to promises fixed the issue however.

I moved from this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean>{
     return new Observable<boolean>(resolve => {

          resolve.complete(true);
        //or
          resolve.complete(false);

    });
}
```

to this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot){
     return true;
        //or
          return false;

    });
}
```

Comment: I switched my guards over to Promises to try this out.  It works!  I am at a loss as to why that would matter, but I'm going to roll with this.  Thank you Victor96!

Comment: Change resolve.complete(true); to resolve.next(true); and it should work. As per https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards
>Accordingly, a routing guard can return an Observable<boolean> or a Promise<boolean> and the router will wait for the observable to resolve to true or false.
And complete does not return any element but next does.

Comment: For me, `resolve.next(true); resolve.complete()` did not work, but using a `Promise` did.

Comment: observer.complete(value) does nothing... you wanted to do `observer.next(true); observer.complete` or simply `Observable.of(true)`. This answer is unfortunately bad advice.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone coming here because of the error message, this was happening to us because we were returning a void Observable. You need to return at lease some value like "true".

```
return of(true);
```

Comment: changing `of()` to `of(undefined)` worked for me

Answer (score 10):

Had the same issue because I was doing a .first() after a this.http.get();
Http.get returns a cold observable so first was unnecessary because cold observables unsubscribe themselves automatically.

this.http.get().pipe(first()); -> EmptyError: no elements in sequence

Comment: you are  saver on this one, tight deadline, wouldn't have thought about this.

Answer (score 7):

Add this property to your route.

```
pathMatch: 'full
```

for eg.

```
{ pathMatch: 'full', path: "", component: HomeComponent }
```

It worked for me.

Comment: There is no need to change app routes in order to fix this (as of today). A new version of RxJS came out with a fix for this error. Upgrade RxJS to version 5.5.4.

Answer (score 6):

I will also share my experience with this error in *RxJS 6.5.3* when using the `last()` operator. 
The problem could be solved by applying a default value like:

```
.pipe(
  last(null, []) // predicate = null, defaultValue = []
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue in Angular 6 / RxJs 6 and found it was due to my guard having a redirect and complete right after it.

Before:

```
if (!res) {
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
  observer.complete(); // <-- This was the offender
}
```

After:

```
if (!res) {
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, using version 5.5.12 of rxjs, I had trouble with this in a CanActivate scenario. But the solution for me was very easy in the end. I changed my code from

```
const guard: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
```

to

```
const guard: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
```

Calling

```
guard.next(...);
guard.complete();
```

later. That did the trick. So no .first nor promises needed in my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error because of Angular's router `expandSegment` function which uses a RXJS `first` operator.

It was occurring because a `canDeactivate` handler for the component was miss handled and was returning an already complete observable (for a dialog), causing the router to complete without having anything emitted, thus resulting in the error from `first`.

The fix for me was to move a line of code that cleared the old dialog observable from a variable, from a `tap` (which didn't run if an error happened or it completes too quickly) to a `finalize` operator, which would always run.

My particular situation was I have a can deactivate that checks if user has unsaved changes on the page and asks whether to discard or stay on the page. If the app was in the middle of saving those changes and they pick discarded, then  something weird happens and the bit of code that clears the dialog observable (it records it so can pass to subsequent `canDeactivate`s, so don't get multiple dialogs popups) never runs and each subsequent call to the `canDeactivate` gets immediately completed and causes the error.

Comment: The case when `Guard` depends on a hanging stream.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when `toPromise()` was deprecated and I started using `lastValueFrom()` instead.

In my case, I was cancelling API calls if one was already under way:

```
  private async loadBoard() {
    this.cancelBoardFetch.next();
    const board = await lastValueFrom(this.service.getBoard().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.cancelBoardFetch)
    ));

    // This errors if cancelBoardFetch is called during an existing request.
  }
```

I changed it to use `startWith()` to ensure something was always returned:

```
  private async loadBoard() {
    this.cancelBoardFetch.next();
    const board = await lastValueFrom(this.service.getBoard().pipe(
      startWith(undefined),
      takeUntil(this.cancelBoardFetch)
    ));

    // Add a check to see if we cancelled, if so do nothing.
    if (!board) {
      return;
    }

    // Do something with the result
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @adam0101 above, we hit this error when we upgraded from rxjs to the version 7.8.1 from the version 6.6.7.

The error was triggered in two situations.

The first one was when changing toPromise function to lastValueFrom or firstValueFrom. The best way to handle this was to add a defaultValue in the configuration settings of the function.

So...

```
function.toPromise() ---> lastValueFrom(function, {defaultValue: undefined})
```

or

```
function.toPromise() ---> firstValueFrom(function, {defaultValue: undefined})
```

Here the related documentation: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise

The second case was triggered by a delayWhen that had a return EMPTY. By modifying to of(undefined) resolved our issue.

So our wrong:

```
delayWhen(() => {(...some code); return EMPTY;})
```

Becomes:

```
delayWhen(() => {(...some code); return of(undefined);})
```

Here the related documentation: https://rxjs.dev/6-to-7-change-summary#delaywhen

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the whole response instead of response.body

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30553561)

Answer (score 0):

As this page is the first Google result for this error, below is another pattern that demonstrates the underlying issue more generally.

Having gotten very comfortable with observables and rxjs operators, going back to a promise-based approach had me scratching my head:

```
await lastValueFrom(myConfirmation().pipe(
  filter(confirmation => !!confirmation),
  switchMap(() => myOperation())))
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

If `confirmation` evaluates to false, the `then` block is never reached, the promise is not able to complete and an `EmptyError: no elements in sequence` error is thrown.

The solution in this case is to remove the `filter`, so that the `then` block is still reached, even if `confirmation` evaluates to false.

```
await lastValueFrom(myConfirmation().pipe(
  switchMap((confirmation) => {
    if (confirmation) {
      return myOperation();
    } else {
      return of(false)
    }
  })))
  .then(response => {
    if (response) {
      console.log(response);
    } else {
      console.log('Operation was not confirmed');
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

Answer (score -1):

None of the above worked for it. This is what worked for me. In the route definition:

```
{ path: '', component: WelcomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```