# How do I trace an `EmptyError: no elements in sequence` bug in an angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm working on an Angular project that's throwing an error: `core.js:1350 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): EmptyError: no elements in sequence` but I can't seem to trace it to any of my app source code.  The stack trace all points to rxjs classes.

Can anyone tell me how I can debug this error so that I can get to the real error in the code?

```
core.js:1350 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): EmptyError: no elements in sequence
EmptyError: no elements in sequence
    at new EmptyError (EmptyError.js:28)
    at FirstSubscriber._complete (first.js:154)
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:122)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._complete (mergeMap.js:150)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:122)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (Subscriber.js:140)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:122)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (ArrayObservable.js:124)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
    at new EmptyError (EmptyError.js:28)
    at FirstSubscriber._complete (first.js:154)
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:122)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._complete (mergeMap.js:150)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:122)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (Subscriber.js:140)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:122)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (ArrayObservable.js:124)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at eval (zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4621)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: If you recently moved to rxjs 5.5.3, look [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3151)

Comment: It's actually using "rxjs": "^5.5.2" in both the before(when it was working) and after

Comment: Oh I see, the `^` means npm will install 5.5.3 - you're right that was the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug is due to the last version of Angular's Router.
You can reverse your version or append `pathMatch: 'full'` to all of your routes.

See [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20752).

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhm22.png)