# Angular 2 child routes not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a child route history and i get an empty error.

> Uncaught (in promise): EmptyError: no elements in sequence
>   EmptyError: no elements in sequence

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
{path: 'calories', pathMatch: 'full', component: CaloriesComponent, canActivate: [UserService], children: [
    {path: 'history', pathMatch: 'full', component: CaloriesHistoryComponent, canActivate: [UserService]}
  ]},
```

Comment: Your UserService is probably incorrect, and completes without emitting true or false. Why the `pathMatch: 'full'`, BTW?

Comment: `canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.isAuth().then(
      response => {
         if (response.success) {
           this._logged_user.next(new User(response.data));
          return true;
        }else {
           this._logged_user.next(null);
           this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
           return false;
        }
      }
    );
  } `

Comment: Why are you setting the same can activate on the child route? The parent route authguard will propagate to all children

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when using RxJS 5.5.3 with angular (version 4/5), so just skip RxJS 5.5.3, and use RxJS 5.5.4 by adding "rxjs": "^5.5.4" to your project package.json

Comment: i have rxjs: '^5.4.1' in package.json

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any issues with your code. I searched the error use gave and I found this post about it. Seems to be relevant to your question. I hope this helps.

[Here is the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131476/emptyerror-no-elements-in-sequence)