# How to handle "EmptyError: no elements in sequence"?

Tags: angular, rxjs

My issue has nothing to do with the [Angular router bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131476/emptyerror-no-elements-in-sequence).

I have a component that can be dragged and dropped. The code for the drag and drop functionality looks like this:

```
@HostListener('mousedown')
onMousedown(): void {
  const mousemove$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
  const mouseup$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');

  const modifiedMouseMove$ = mousemove$
    .map(some transformations)
    .takeUntil(mouseup$);

  modifiedMouseMove$.subscribe(do something on each move);
  modifiedMouseMove$.last().subscribe(drop the item)
}
```

If I just "click" on the item, I get:

```
Error: EmptyError { message: 'no elements in sequence', ... }
```

I'm assuming the issues is that when I click, it fires a `mousedown -> mouseup`, with no `mousemove` events in between. Causing the `modifiedMouseMove$` to be "empty" and the call to `.last()` returns nothing. This error does not impact the functionality of my application. I can catch it and do nothing:

```
modifiedMouseMove$.last().subscribe(() => drop the item, (err) => {
  if (err.name === 'EmptyError') { 
    return;
  } else {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

Now it doesn't show up in the console anymore, but purposefully swallowing an error seems...bad. **How do I actually handle the error?**

Should I not activate the second subscription (with the `last()` operator) if there are no mouse moves? If so, what's the best way to do that?

Is there a magical operator that will only subscribe if there is an event and leave the observable cold otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want just the last item from an Observable and you're fine when there's none it's better to use the [`takeLast(1)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeLast) operator:

```
modifiedMouseMove$.takeLast(1).subscribe(...)
```

The `last()` and `first()` operators require one and only one matching item. Any other situation results into an error notification.

Comment: +1 (upvoted) Thank you - this looks promising. I will try it when I get back to my computer and will accept if it works.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Martin's answer. Would also add a `defaultIfEmpty` to handle after `takeLast(1)` to avoid no elements being emitted.

E.g.,

```
takeLast(1).defaultIfEmpty(element).subscribe()
```